# Cox regression with binary time-varying covariate

Tags: panel-data, cox-model, binary-data, dependent-variable

I am researching the association between menopause and the incidence of diabetes(outcome).

I have a baseline and three follow-up assessments. Given that women transition from non-menopausal to menopausal status over time, I need to treat menopause status as a time-varying exposure in my analysis. This exposure variable is binary, taking on values 0 and 1.

My data is long format and I am working with stata 17. I am  interested in implementing a time-varying Cox proportional hazards model to account for the changing menopause status over time. I defined follow up time . please see below

generate FUtime = round((datend - datexam) / 365.25, 0.1)
lab var  FUtime     "Length of the period, uncorrected (years)"

```
* Here I only correct if the participant developped diabetes during the period
* if the participant already had diabetes, the length of period is unchanged
* eventually, delete the periods where the participant had diabetes at start
* such as drop if incDIAB==1 & DIAB==1

generate FUtime_cor = FUtime
replace  FUtime_cor = FUtime_cor/2 if incDIAB==1 & DIAB!=1
lab var  FUtime_cor "Length of the period, corrected (years)"
 now I want to do time varing cox model but i could not find a command to consider menopause as time varying ?
```

Comment: General study design comment: the starting time for menopause is pretty arbitrary, depending on the data source.  In the future you'd get a much stronger design by longitudinally measuring [various marker levels](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-94-007-7696-8_9).

Comment: in my reserch data for every follow up they asked women (are you menopaused?) so i have 4 menopause status in 4 times (baseline and follow ups ) and my question is how can I consider menopause in stata command as a timevaring in long format data?